# How to add query params to context of apollo-server-express

Tags: node.js, express, apollo-server

I'm using apollo-server-express as so right now:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import { getUser } from 'meteor/apollo';
import schema from './api';

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const user = await getUser(req.headers.authorization);

    return {
      user,
    };
  },
  playground: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  introspection: true,
  uploads: false,
});

server.applyMiddleware({
  app: WebApp.connectHandlers,
  path: '/graphql',
});
```

I'd like to add another field to the `context` which has all the query params from the URL my user is visiting.

It seems that the [`req` object passed to the `context`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#middleware-specific-context-fields) function by `apollo-server-express` is of type [`express.Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/50adc95acf873e714256074311353232fcc1b5ed/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts) which ought to have a `req.query` object. However, when I try to access that like so:

```
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    console.log('### query', req.query);
    console.log('### params', req.params);
    const user = await getUser(req.headers.authorization);

    return {
      user,
    };
  },
```

and visit my app at http://localhost:3000/u/3q2PcjRwyiqR2ywHM/BK2CiG7fN3P7Z5xvy?editToken=qdj3RRYjCuMxFNRnz (note the `?editToken=...`)

I see the following log lines:

```
I20220417-15:08:54.477(-5)? ### query {}
I20220417-15:08:54.478(-5)? ### params undefined
I20220417-15:08:54.570(-5)? ### query {}
I20220417-15:08:54.571(-5)? ### params undefine
```

What is the correct way to access URL query params when creating the context for apollo-server-express? I'm specifically trying to add the `editToken` to the context.

Answer (score 0):

Was wondering also. Decide to leave my solution
In context - return not only user, but add user obj to req (req.user = user) and return req itself and in resolvers you can use full req obj

Also you can add editToken to headers and get it in code not so visible for users

And sure we can't visit your app on your localhost :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34502069)

Comment: Asker asked how to get query params from req that was processed by apollo-server futher for processing. And my answer provide option how get what was asked - req object itself further in processing pipe. And my answer do not need any reply from asker or any clarification - it is self-sufficient